# Extract fitted values in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I’m trying to exctract the values from a fitted model. So far I keep getting errors  with all the suggestions I could find on the internet.

Here is my code

```
plotPoints(absorbance~time,data=a)
f1 = fitModel(absorbance~B*time^(A),data=a)
plotFun(f1(time)~time,add=TRUE,col="red")
fitted(f1)
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Thank you for your time and help

Sebastian

Comment: Does `f1$fitted` not work? What package is this?

Comment: As Matt mentioned, no one can help unless you specify what package this code comes from. We're not mind readers.

Comment: sorry, it's RStudio. I tried f1$fitted: > f1$fitted
Error in f1$fitted : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: the package is `mosaic` :), see my answer below

Comment: No, you misunderstood. You're using code from an external package that you haven't named. Another user has done part of your work for you and figured that out on their own (mosaic, apparently), but in the future, you need to provide that information in your question. RStudio has nothing to do with this.

Comment: sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

f1 is not a model, try:

```
library(mosaic)
a <- data.frame(absorbance = sample(1:10,10),time = sample(1:10,10),B=sample(1:10,10))
plotPoints(absorbance~time,data=a)
f1 = fitModel(absorbance~B*time^(A),data=a)
plotFun(f1(time)~time,add=TRUE,col="red")
fitted(model(f1))
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mosaic/versions/0.14.4/topics/fitModel